# HTML is not displaying spaces of mysql value

Tags: html, css

I have a mysql value like this:

```
hello 
hello
```

but HTML displays it like this:

```
hello hello
```

how to can I display it like in mysql?

Comment: Try using [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag or assigning the css rule [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to your text tag.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL? Don't you see the same thing when you write plain HTML?

Comment: And the solution is the same as when you're writing HTML directly.

Comment: If you're using PHP you can use the `nl2br()` function.

Comment: thanks @HaoWu . it is perfectly worked.

Comment: thanks @Barmar . I deleted mysql tag.